# Original formulation of the axioms of rationality

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, decision-theory, rationality

Completeness and transitivity are considered to be the two axioms of rationality in case of decisions under certainty. I wanted to know when were these axioms first proposed, by whom and the first paper where they were proposed.

I know Allen and Hicks broke away from the paradigm of Cardinal Utility and that Pareto and Fisher had also noted the possible efficacy of an ordinal view of utility. Samuelson developed the Revealed Preference Approach around the same time.

Did Allen and Hicks first propose the axioms mathematically? What was the paper? How was it received initially?

Comment: this seems to be duplicate (or perhaps better word would be already answered by beside other things) this older question: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/33121/who-is-the-first-one-to-equate-rational-with-complete-and-transitive-preferen/40905#40905.

Comment: Yes, this answers my question, thanks